# C# tcpclient / server to external ip doesnt work

Tags: c#, server, client, port, router

so I've got a server/client model which are exchanging data. This is basically the network part from the server:

Server:

```
...
listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 4711);
listener.Start();
while(true){
TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
}
...
```

Client:

```
...
TcpClient c = new TcpClient("myip", 4711);
StreamReader inStream = new StreamReader(c.GetStream());
...
```

If i connect to "localhost" via my client it all works as it should, same for my internal ipv4 address. I assumed that this should work for my external ip as well, somehow it doesn't I always get the message that the server refuses the connection.

My router is a FRITZ!Box 6490 Cable (kdg). I enabled portforwarding for 4711 in it and in my firewall. When I check 4711 via http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it says my port is closed though. I guess that is the problem? Or am I doing something wrong? I usually give my client the external ipv4 adress which doesnt work, if i give my external ipv6 it does work, but only for people in my network (internal and external ipv6 are the same for me, i think that's just the way it is probably).

My ipv4 is running on a DS-Lite-Tunnle , does that mean that someone only can connect via ipv6 to my computer?

Furthermore I read about that ipv6 causes problems with portforwarding, so i disabled ipv6 on my computer, but that did not work either.

Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was speaking to my router provider and they told me there is nothing I can do about it. The only way I could change this is phoning my ISP and tell them I want ipv4 back. Opening ports / Connecting to my Computer from outside is not possible with a DS-Lite-Tunnel (Thats what they told me).